# Lame tags in mp3 frame

Tags: mp3, lame

It's known that mp3 frame has a strict structure. Mp3 header - tags - audio data.
There is a problem with LAME tag. It may be in the end or further from a header than it should be(not after VBR tag or not after the header for e.g). My queston is why? And how am I supposed to handle it in case I want to extract audio data? I tried to find it out from LAME website, but actually no info about the location. Also, I couldn't find any info about the length(http://gabriel.mp3-tech.org/mp3infotag.html 228 bytes, but I am not sure that It's universal)